# Can you stop clipping whilst building in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Are there any console commands or tricks in Fallout 4 to enable you to place objects next to or slightly overlapping other objects in settlements like fence to remove annoying spaces where the collisions normally stop you from placing objects?

Comment: Mod: [Simple Intersection (Nexus)](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/2683/?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you CAN get around the clipping. Most folks will use a rug because it's small, but you could use a piece of fence or any object really. I'll use a rug because it's simple to explain.

- Place your rug on the ground away from ANY other objects.
- Place the object you want to clip on top of the rug.
- Select the rug with a long press of <kbd>E</kbd> (on PC, whatever select is on your console), this will also select your second (or more) object.
- Move the rug and the other object, but only the rug will be looked at as far as clipping goes.
- After you've placed your object store the rug for future use, or move it w/ a single <kbd>E</kbd> press to clip another object into your wall/building/whatever.

Answer (score 4):

This method only works for PC currently - nothing can be done on Xbox or PS4 until next year when mods will be movable to consoles.

- Enable building mode
- Place the "building" on a location of your choice
- Open the in game console (press <kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>~</kbd> on your keyboard depending on layout)
- Type the command `tcl` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>
- Now target your "building" and press <kbd>E</kbd> so you can move the "building"
- Hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to cancel the movement of your gate
- the "building" snaps back to it's original location, but this time it has no collision and you can place any object through it
- Build a  new "building" next to the first "building" in such a way that the edges clip through each other, leaving no gaps
- (IMPORTANT!) After you've finished building, open your console again and type `tcl` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to disable the no-clip

One thing to remember is that an object placed or edited in TCL mode will be untargetable until you turn off TCL mode. This means that you can only place or move an object once per TCL session, so to speak.

The trick for moving your whole structure (press and hold <kbd>E</kbd>) will still usually work for buildings placed in this method but there may be times it will fail.